# What sort of propulsion technology would allow spaceships to lift off the surface of the Earth and ascend into space like we see in sci-fi movies?

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science, space-travel, propulsion

In many sci-fi films, spacecraft are easily capable of lifting off the surface of a planet like a Harrier and ascending into space. It's clear that the propulsion system/jet engines aren't your average chemical rockets, as the [ships](http://www.horror-movies.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Prometheus-Ship.jpg) are usually very sleek and lack a huge reservoir of propellant. Ion propulsion also seems to be out of the question due to limited thrust density.

I'd love to know if any aerospace engineers or physicists out there can chime in to discuss the plausibility of these types of ships. It would be amazing to see them in my lifetime, and it'd be a huge disappointment if they're not really in the realm of possibility at this time. That being said, I've always wanted to get to the bottom of this and figure out what sort of technology would be necessary.

Comment: I view this as on topic - e.g. a rocket works by throwing stuff out the back. You can either throw a lot of stuff out somewhat fast (current model), or a little bit of stuff *really* fast (presumably how a scifi-like engine would work). The current answers seem to be working along these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for in general is an SSTO (Single Stage To Orbit -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-stage-to-orbit -- meaning it doesn't drop off boosters on the way up) rocket with a high payload fraction ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_fraction -- meaning most of the spacecraft isn't fuel and fuel tank).

Unfortunately, current SSTO designs have very low payload fraction.  They would be a lot of fuel tank and a little useful payload, so much so that those designs just aren't used.

The bottom line is, to do what you want we'd need an engineering breakthrough.  *Not* a physics breakthrough -- a spacecraft propulsion system like the one you're talking about wouldn't violate physical laws as we know them.  But we've got no idea how to build a highly efficient rocket (high ISP -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse -- how much thrust you can get out of a bit of fuel ) that is also a high-thrust rocket.  We have designs for rockets with far higher ISP than the shuttle's main engines, but the the rocket would be too heavy to lift itself off the ground.  It would just sit on the ground, firing away, wasting fuel.  Although it'd be wasting fuel very efficiently.

If someone ever develops a thermonuclear reactor that you can fit in a soda can and fuse a kilogram of deuterium every second, you'd see rockets that'd go straight up, laughing at the Earth's gravity all the way, but we don't even know the design principles for such a beast.

Comment: Specific impulse limitations are a physics problem, not an engineering problem. We have very efficient propulsion designs that are very close to the theoretical maximum of physically existing and possible fuels and power sources. The only large and "expensive" part of a rocket is the first stage, anyway. Any technology that can give us the first 2000-3000m/s and 40km altitude cheaply will be the economical solution. After that rather modest upper stages can do the job quite well.

Comment: @CuriousOne No.  There's no physical law against a very efficient, low-mass fusion reactor, or against more effective production and storage of anti-matter, or against power storage in general very far in advance of what we have today, any of which might be used to create high-ISP, high-thrust engines.  And in your declaration of "the only large and 'expensive' part of a rocket is the first stage," where would you fit the STS?  The "first stage" there, if there is one, would be the solid rocket boosters.

Comment: The main physics problem is not the reactor, the problem is how to get rid of the waste heat of a 100GW reactor that is not 100% efficient in a 10m scale spaceship! Thermodynamics would, unfortunately, not  be sleeping, even if we could manage to get the necessary power density out of a nuclear source like antimatter. Look at the massive cooling required even for a 1GW power plant!

Comment: @CuriousOne I'll ignore your confusion about anti-matter being "nuclear."  There is -- again -- no physical law against an energy source having as many 9s as you want in efficiency.

Comment: There is an engineering law against your spaceship heating up to 12000K while staying functional and nobody has made anything thermodynamic that is near perfect, especially not at the 100GW level. Generating energy is NOT the only physical problem in the design of launch systems and just assuming that there is some magic formula to make things 99.9999% efficient is neither physics nor engineering. That is really just fiction, in which case even a broom can fly.

Comment: I don't remember anyone but you saying that the spaceship would reach 12000K.  And at this point I'll leave up to the votes as to whether or not there is a difference between assuming that a viable high-ISP, high-thrust system wouldn't violate know physical laws, and assuming that broomsticks can fly.
NOTE: Broomsticks are not to be altered by the addition of nanotechnology or other advanced technology for this purpose.  Offer void where prohibited.  Not valid in U.S. Virgin Islands.

Comment: I was making a joke. Seriously. If you want to generate 100GW on the 10m scale for this kind of propulsion, you have to be willing and able to remove at least around 10GW of waste heat for a couple of minutes. That's a very optimistic engineering assumption. I don't think anybody can give you a realistic mechanism for that that is not based on wishful thinking. And that's why we have rockets... unlike broomsticks and scifi spaceships they actually work. Other than that... I want my flying car, too... it just doesn't exist, either.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses. Apologies for coming back to this so late (it's been a busy summer), but I wanted to get more details from you and @CuriousOne. In addition to somehow scaling a fusion reactor or antimatter propulsion, I've read up on metallic hydrogen as being a [potential game-changer](http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/215/1/012194/pdf/1742-6596_215_1_012194.pdf) with respect to an SSTO spacecraft. Any thoughts on what this sort of technology would allow and how much of this sort of fuel would be needed to get off an Earth size planet?

Answer (score 3):

The answer based on accepted physics is trivial: none. That's why they call it science FICTION. One can theoretically reduce the amount of propellant, but then the required power these ships would have to develop would go trough the roof. Keep in mind that a medium sized rocket develops on the order of 10GW of power for a few minutes during first stage burn and then something like 1GW for six, seven minutes during second stage burn to get to LEO. Reduce the amount of propellant by a factor of 10 to make a "sleek" ship, now you would need 100GW during the first stage burn. In effect that would be a giant waste of energy for no good reason.

There is nothing really wrong with rockets except for the one thing that SpaceX is trying to fix, right now: we are basically throwing a machine of the size, cost and complexity of an airliner away after the first use. Once we stop doing that space access will become cheaper by quite a bit. It won't become really cheap (as in \$49 to the Moon and back), but it will, for all practical purposes, become cheap enough, given the difficulties and cost to survive in space once we get there (the launch technology can't get rid of those). A cost reduction far below the order of \$100k per person for manned flights will therefor have next to no economic impact on any scientifically imaginable form of space economy.

The more interesting questions, physically and technologically, are related to space elevators and electromagnetic mass drivers and such... but those are not "ships" in the sense that you are looking for, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of the type of spacecraft we see in *Star Wars|Trek* and similar, it is clear these cannot be reaction-based rockets.

Look at the power that has to be unleashed to get a Space Shuttle into orbit and compare it to what happens in the movies; The *Millenium Falcon*, for instance, is a few times larger than a Space Shuttle yet it scoots into space with barely a condensation trail. Note that changing the efficiency of the fuel source just changes the amount of fuel you need - it doesn't alter the amount of energy required to get into space.

We have to conclude, therefore, that these craft are using a novel technology to fly. Anti-gravity repulsion perhaps? Or some [*space propeller*](http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/vprop/) that pushes against the fabric of space-time?

In any case, the technology is well beyond anything that currently exists. You might live to see it - if you are very young and live a healthy life :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a far out suggestion.  Mass distorts space-time.  The space-time around a black hole is significantly distorted, as it is around a galaxy, and even our sun and earth.  So space-time is a thing that can be altered.

We only need to create a machine that can directly distort space-time though some physical phenomenon rather than with mass alone.  Then we can distort the space-time directly in front of our spacecraft such that it will begin moving in that direction as though there were a huge mass in that direction.

... only ....  Heh heh, simple idea.  Almost certainly impossible to implement.